# SafeCracker Entries Created With Status “Closed”

Tags: safecracker

Here is how its setup.

The Channel: Personal Trainer Directory

#### Edit Group Assignments

Status Groups: Statuses

#### Edit Preferences

Default Status: Open

#### Member Group Settings

Channel Assignment

Can post and edit entries in Personal Trainer Directory: Yes

Module Access Privileges

Can access module SafeCracker: Yes

#### SafeCracker Module Settings

Personal Trainer Directory

Default Status: Open

SafeCracker tag

```
{exp:safecracker
channel="personal_trainer_directory"
return="/member/profile"
entry_id="{segment_3}"
status="open"
safecracker_head="no"
use_live_url="no"
url_title=""
}
```

The entries are being created fine, just dont understand why they are showing up as closed still.  Is there anything that I forgot?

**Edit:** I added the Member Group Settings section above, I forgot to add that initially so I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Does the member group who is submitting the form have permission to post entries to the channel?

Comment: @JasonVarga in the Member Group Settings, I have `Can post and edit entries in Personal Trainer Directory: Yes` and `Can access module SafeCracker: Yes` for that member group.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Also make sure you've assigned a Status group to that channel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that the member adding the entry is in a group that has access to the non-closed statuses.  Before you do that, ensure a status group is assigned to the channel.  Superadmins can use Open and Closed even without a status group assigned; but others can't - and that is the most common cause of what you're seeing.

Comment: thank you so much! this fixed it! this 1 was a little tricky i never htought to check the specific status

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem. Try removing `status="open"` from the Safecracker tag altogether. Worked for me.